# If variable contains word, show it and get line number

Tags: php

So I trying to check "if text file on server contains word, show it and display his line number" but i only know how to check "if text file contains word". Anybody have sugesstions how to do it? I saw many tutorials but there are about local text files.

For now I have only this function

```
   function readStrLine($str, $n) {
    $lines = explode(PHP_EOL, $str);
    return $lines[$n-1];
}
```

But I need line number.

For example I have text file saved on my server. **examplesite.com/file.txt** with 
this content:

```
 ABCDEF
 123456
 QWERTY
```

For now program reads content and checks if there is containing word. But I need the number of this line where this word is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Example:

```
<?php

$desiredWord = 'apple';

$fileString = file_get_contents('asd.txt');

$lines = explode(PHP_EOL, $fileString);

$results = [];
foreach ($lines as $lineNumber => $line) {
    if (strpos($line, $desiredWord) !== false) {
        $results[] = ($lineNumber + 1) .":{$line}";
    }
}

foreach ($results as $result) {
    echo '<pre>' . print_r($result, true) . '</pre>';
}
```

Input file content:

```
apple
asdfsdf
vs
werwerwer
llll
hhheeheh
there is an apple on the tree
the tree does not fall far from it's apple
```

Output:

```
1:apple

7:there is an apple on the tree

8:the tree does not fall far from it's apple
```

---

You can go through on the lines with a foreach. The `$lineNumber` key contains the line index you are currently reading, and the `$line` is the string of the current line. The explode function will index your array from 0, so first line index will be 0 when you read it. That's why the + 1 in this line: `$results[] = ($lineNumber + 1) .":{$line}";`

With the `if (strpos($line, $desiredWord) !== false)` you are checking if you find the desired word in the given line. If you want only one result you can return here, but if you would like to collect all of the lines where the word can be found, then you store the found lines like this in the `$results`

Finally you can check the findings with the second foreach, or any other way - depends on your implementation.